# (IOS) XCode - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, 3d

I just finishing building a game on Unity 5.6 to work on IOS, however when I open it on XCode and build it onto my iPhone I get this error. I have looked around and couldn't find a fix and hopefully you guys could help me.

So this is what I have done so far.

- In building settings I changed 'Always search user paths' to 'yes'
- Got rid of spaces in the header search paths
- Restarted XCode, clean, and build
- Deleted project.workspace and opened the project again in Xcode

The game works perfectly in Unity3D on the IOS platform. However when I try to search for NDComPlatform in the project files I can't seem to find anything. I think it might be missing the framework or something?

I have attached an image of the error.

[Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpIW3.png)

Hope you guys can help me out :)

Thank you,

JEEZY

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same kind of issue.